# Read output from C in Python simultaneously as it's being printed

Tags: python, c, gcc, subprocess

I have a simple C program that prints numbers 1 to 10 every 5 seconds. I want to have a Python script that reads and prints these numbers as they're being printed in C. I have these two files here, but right now test.c prints everything from 1-10 at once. How can I have them printed from test.py as they're being printed in test.c?

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CalledProcessError

cmd = "./test"

print("Running..")
with Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line, end='') # process line here

if p.returncode != 0:
    raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, p.args)
```

And here is test.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
 
    int i;
    
    //Print numbers from 1 to 10
    for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
      sleep(5);
      printf("%d ",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've been compiling test.c like:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

How can I make the C file print numbers one by one? How can I simultaneously read output from C files as they're being printed?

Comment: Add a `fflush(stout);` in the loop.

Comment: Apparently adding a "\n" in the printf statement prints the numbers every 5 seconds now, but Python still reads them at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Shawn's comment, adding `fflush(stdout)` flushes the output stream the solves the problem. Also adding a newline `printf("%d \n",i);` makes the c program print numbers every 5 seconds.